# Hive SQL Full Outer Join with Where Clause

Tags: sql, hiveql, where-clause, full-outer-join

I am creating a full outer join with a where clause. However, it can only generate inner join result. I suspect that it is due to the where clause, but I do need this where condition being added. So how can I create a query with both needs meet (both the where condition and full outer join)? Here is my query.

```
select
  t1.key1 as key1_1
, t1.key2 as key2_1
, t1.key3 as key3_1
, t1.date as date_1
, t1.v1
, t2.key1 as key1_2
, t2.key2 as key2_2
, t2.key3 as key3_2
, t2.date as date_2
, t2.v2
from t1 
full outer join t2
on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.key2 = t2.key2 and t1.key3 = t2.key3 
where datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
;
```

Sample data

```
t1
key1 key2 key3 date        v1
A1   B1   C1   2015-01-01  10
A1   B2   C2   2015-01-01  11

t2
key1 key2 key3 date        v2
A1   B1   C1   2015-01-01  20
A1   B1   C1   2015-01-03  30
A1   B1   C1   2015-02-01  40
A1   B1   C1               50
A1   B1   C2   2015-01-02  60
```

Desired result

```
key1_1 key2_1 key3_1 date_1     v1 key1_2 key2_2 key3_2 date_2     v2
A1     B1     C1     2015-01-01 10 A1     B1     C1     2015-01-01 20
A1     B1     C1     2015-01-01 10 A1     B1     C1     2015-01-03 30
                                   A1     B1     C1     2015-02-01 40
                                   A1     B1     C1                50
                                   A1     B1     C2     2015-01-02 60
A1     B2     C2     2015-01-01 11
```

These are all the scenarios that I can think of as now. I can add in if I find any missing scenarios. My point here is the fact that the following results should be included:

1. if the two tables meet all those conditions set up with the keys and date, then it is included as shown in line 1 and 2 in the desired result.
2. if any of those conditions is not met, then we will keep one table's information in the result as shown in line 3, 4, 5, and 6 in the desired result.

EDIT:
Based on @Gordon Linoff 's suggestion, I used a union all to resolve the issue. Please see my solution in my answer post below.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your `where` clause turns this into an `inner join`.

Comment: Learn what FULL JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a FULL JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN requiring some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows NULL-extended for columns of such table(s), ie leaves only RIGHT/LEFT/INNER [sic] JOIN ON rows, ie "turns FULL JOIN into RIGHT/LEFT/INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to my own question, based on @Gordon Linoff 's suggestion shown in the discussion session.

```
create table t3 as
select *, row_number () over () as id from t1;

create table t4 as
select *, row_number () over () as id from t2;

create table t5 as
select 
  t1.id as id_1
, t1.key1 as key1_1
, t1.key2 as key2_1
, t1.key3 as key3_1
, t1.date as date_1
, t1.v1
, t2.id as id_2
, t2.key1 as key1_2
, t2.key2 as key2_2
, t2.key3 as key3_2
, t2.date as date_2
, t2.v2
from t3 as t1 
full outer join t4 as t2
on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.key2 = t2.key2 and t1.key3 = t2.key3 
where datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
;

set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
create table t6 as
select
  t1.id as id_1
, t1.key1 as key1_1
, t1.key2 as key2_1
, t1.key3 as key3_1
, t1.date as date_1
, t1.v1
, null as id_2
, null as key1_2
, null as key2_2
, null as key3_2
, null as date_2
, null as v2
from t3 as t1 
where t1.id not in (select t2.id_1 from t5 as t2 where t2.id_1 is not null)
;

create table t7 as
select
  null as id_1
, null as key1_1
, null as key2_1
, null as key3_1
, null as date_1
, null as v1
, t1.id as id_2
, t1.key1 key1_2
, t1.key2 key2_2
, t1.key3 key3_2
, t1.date date_2
, t1.v2
from t4 as t1 
where t1.id not in (select t2.id_2 from t5 as t2 where t2.id_2 is not null)
;

create table t8 as
select * from t5 union all
select * from t6 union all
select * from t7
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to move the logic to the `on` clause:

```
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and
        t1.key2 = t2.key2 and
        t1.key3 = t2.key3 and
        datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
```

EDIT:

If the above doesn't work, then perhaps you can rewrite the query as a `union all`:

```
select . . . 
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and
        t1.key2 = t2.key2 and
        t1.key3 = t2.key3
where datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
union all
select . . .
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t1.key1 = t2.key1 and
                        t1.key2 = t2.key2 and
                        t1.key3 = t2.key3 and
                        datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
                 )
union all
select . . .
from t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from t1
                  where t1.key1 = t2.key1 and
                        t1.key2 = t2.key2 and
                        t1.key3 = t2.key3 and
                        datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5
                 );
```

I'm not 100% sure that Hive will accept these correlation clauses either.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried it and it shows me the following error message: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '5' (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: @Counter10000 . . . I thought the second version worked.  It didn't?

Comment: It did. For some reason, I cannot accept two posts here. So after I accept my own post, yours is canceled automatically.

Comment: @Counter10000 . . . You can *upvote* as many answers (or questions) as you like, however you can only accept one answer to each question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you have already realized is that the `where` forces `t1.date` and `t2.date` to exist. You just need to avoid this assumption, like:

```
(t1.date is null) or (t2.date is null) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5)
```

Comment: Thanks Lajos. Are you saying that I should use the following join condition? from t1 
full outer join t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.key2 = t2.key2 and t1.key3 = t2.key3 
where (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) <-5) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) >5) or (t1.date is null) or (t2.date is null);

Comment: @Counter10000 my point is that if any of the operands in your where clause is null, then the where will return false, resulting in something very similar to inner join. To avoid that, I would suggest to keep your exact where clause, but add null checks to make sure that in the case of null the tuple will not be filtered out.

Comment: Thank you. Then should I add the other two conditions for the date diff that is out of the range (-5,5) ? I am referring to these two conditions: (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) <-5),  (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) >5).

Comment: @Counter10000 it depends on the actual goal. I do not have enough information to determine whether that's the solution for you, but if you add those criteria as well to the where condition, then the where condition will be true regardless of the actual values of t1.date and t2.date, respectively, hence, it would be equivalent with removing the where clause, since, if there is no where clause in a query, that's a lack of a filter and it's logically equivalent with the case when you have a filter which is always true.

Comment: I think neither serves the goal (see my desired result in the post). If we use this condition `where (t1.date is null) or (t2.date is null) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5)`, then line3 (the one with v2=40) will be missing in the result, since it does not fall in any of these three conditions. If we use this condition `where (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) <-5) or (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) >5) or (t1.date is null) or (t2.date is null)`, then line3 will have column values filled for both t1 and t2. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Counter10000 The initial filter you have used is filtering out anything where the date difference is outside the specified range, that's true, but I think you want to ommit pairing records which do not have a pair with a date close-enough. So, my suggestion is that you can take the logical criteria from the where clause and move it into the on clause, like on t1.key1 = t2.key1 and t1.key2 = t2.key2 and t1.key3 = t2.key3 and (datediff(t1.date, t2.date) between -5 and 5). Of course, then you will remove the where clause, as its content will be inside the on.

Comment: Unfortunately hive sql does not accept inequity condition. Instead, it should be moved to a where clause. Please see the error details in my reply with Gordon's answer.

Comment: @Counter10000 then we should convert this into an equity condition. The first idea that springs to my mind is to write a stored function, which gets the two dates, returns 1 if they are close to each-other and 0 if not and you add yourfunction(t1.date, t2.date) = 1 into your on clause.

Comment: .@Lajos. Agreed. I think it is a bit challenging though to generate such a flag on both tables. Because it is a range for each row and it is constantly changing for every row.  Do you have any suggestion? Personally, I think Gordon's union is comparatively easier, so I've generated a solution based on that idea. I'm still open to your opinion as well. Please let me know if you can think of a way to generate the flag. Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: @Counter10000 The idea I presented in my previous comment is that you could write a stored function, which would have two dates as input, check whether the datediff is between -5 and 5 and return 1 if so, 0 if not. It's not difficult to implement such a stored procedure and you would have such a flag as a result. What I do not know is whether this would violate some HQL limitation. If yes, then this idea is not a solution. If no, then this idea is a solution.